# Figuring out and check this Pattern

Tags: java, regex

So I want my inputs to be one of the following:

**0 = any integer**

*0, 00,
000, 0:0, 00:0,
000:0*

Basically 0-999, followed be an optional colon and 0-9. The pattern I am using is

`([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))|(([0-9]|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))&&\3A&&[0-9])`

Is this code pattern redundant, non-working, or wrong? Will it actually do what I want it to do? I would normally just run it and test it, but it takes a while to utilize and test the code with my application.

Comment: So you want us to test it for you?

Comment: You regex is wrong. Use an online tool/site or offline tools such as regexbuddy or expresso.

Comment: When you have small independently testable items like this simply create a standalone program that calls it if you are not using JUnit or other.

Answer (score 2):

Looking over it:

- The `&&` are no special characters, they have to be matched literally. Therefore this part of the RE will never match your examples.
- The `\3A` should be `\\x3A`. Otherwise it would match the character with code 3 followed by an 'A'.
- using the repetition quantifier `{n,m}` instead of multiple `|` is much easier to read and understand

  ```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3}:\\d");
  ```

Comment: This is not correct. In case of 0 followed by : and a number there will be 2 matches instead of one because the first part of your regex will always match.

Comment: @FailedDev: I can't follow. `0:0` will _only_ be matched by the second part, because using `Matcher.match` the regex must match the complete input. The first part would not match the complete input. Proof: Adding three groups to my regex as in `(\\d{1,3})|(\\d{1,3}):(\\d)` shows that for `0:0` show, that `group(1)` is always `null` - only the second part matches.

Comment: I thought the input is the complete line : 0, 00, 000, 0:0, 00:0, 000:0 and not just an individual "set"

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to devise a regular expression to match every number between 0 and 999. Assuming 009 is a valid number you can basically match three sequences of digits (`[0-9]`), and make the first two optional:

```
[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]
```

The above regex will match `999`, `9`, `19`, `009`, but not `1234` or `9999`.

If `009` is not a valid number, then you need to exclude the `0` from the first two groups above, yielding:

```
([1-9][0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9]
```

That is, if you have a hundreds digit, then it must not be 0 (`[1-9]`), and if you have a tens digit (but not a hundreds digit), then it must also not be 0 (the second `[1-9]` in the regex).

Finally, you need to include the optional part, which is basically a comma followed a digit, yielding the final expression:

```
([1-9][0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9](:[0-9])?
```

You can then run some simple tests with a simple standalone program:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9](?::[0-9])?");      
  System.out.println(p.matcher("999").matches());
  System.out.println(p.matcher("1234").matches());
  System.out.println(p.matcher("9").matches());
  System.out.println(p.matcher("19").matches());
  System.out.println(p.matcher("999:9").matches());
  System.out.println(p.matcher("12:99").matches());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking at online information, but it's always most helpful to get an explanation from a human!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(?::\\d)?");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

It should get you going.

Comment: Please note, that this question is also tagged as `Java`, so C# syntax and classes are not 100% compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working pattern and using JUnit, you could test it with some sample data. This code is expected input validation--so if you're trying to extract those values out of a string, then that's a different pattern and would need to test differently.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,3}(?::\\d)?$");

List<String> samples = Arrays.asList("0", "00", "000", "0:0", "00:0", "000:0");
List<String> failSamples = Arrays.asList("0000", "0000:0", "0:00", "00:00", "000:00");
for (String sample : samples)
{
  assertTrue(sample, pattern.matcher(sample).matches());
}
for (String failSample : failSamples)
{
  assertFalse(failSample, pattern.matcher(failSample).matches());
}
```